# Nested serializers in drf throws error with one to one field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.5

My input json is :

```
{
    "availability": "Current",
    "drive_type": [{
        "drive_name": "drive1",
        "requirements": {
            "performance_unit": "by_iops",          
        }
    }]
}
```

I am getting error Cannot assign "

> OrderedDict([('performance_unit', 'Basic')])":
>   "DriveType.requirements" must be a "Requirements" instance

.I am not able to figure it out to  map in create method for one to one fields in tables

Below are my models.py

```
class ProductLine(models.Model):
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)   

    class Meta:
        db_table = "product_line"


class DriveType(models.Model):
    drive_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)    
    product_line = models.ForeignKey(ProductLine, related_name="drive_type")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "drive_type"


class Requirements(models.Model):
    performance_unit = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    drive_type = models.OneToOneField(DriveType,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name="requirements")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "requirements"
```

Serializers.py :

```
class DriveTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    requirements = RequirementsSerializer(many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = DriveType
        fields = (
        "drive_name","workload_type")


class ProductLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    drive_type = DriveTypeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductLine
        fields = ('availability', "drive_type")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("validate_data",validated_data)
        drive_type_data = validated_data.pop("drive_type")
        product_line = ProductLine.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for drive_data in drive_type_data:
            drive_type = DriveType.objects.create(product_line=product_line, **drive_data)
        return product_line
```

Comment: I have figured out mapping myself and now it works perfectly

Comment: checkout my answer, am i right about the issue? if not please post your solution as answer. this will help others if they face similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have one to one relationship of DriveType and Requirements

So remove `many = True` from *DriveTypeSerializer* for *RequirementsSerializer*

```
class DriveTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    requirements = RequirementsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = DriveType
        fields = ("drive_name","workload_type")
```

> Your input json has only one object of requirements not a list